# Any orientation-preserving automorphism of the annulus is isotopic to the identity

Tags: mapping-class-group

How can I prove that an orientation-preserving self-homeomorphism of the annulus $[0,1]\times S^1$ that preserves each boundary component is isotopic to the identity?

Answer (score 0):

It is false. The mapping class group of the annulus is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and it is generated by a Dehn twist around the core of the annulus, which is to say the map defined as
$$
T(t,\theta)=(t,\theta +2\pi t).
$$ You can find a proof in Farb and Margalit's book *A Primer on Mapping Class Group*.